# C#: конвертирование Enum’ов

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, enum

Время от времени приходится писать весьма стандартный код, когда есть два Enum'а с абсолютно одинаковым содержимым, но находящиеся в разных неймспейсах.

Подключать лишние зависимости - нельзя (ну, по архитектурным соображениям), поэтому возникает вот такой вот (прямо скажем, не особо остроумный) код:

в namespace1:

```
    public enum InTheRace
    {
        First,
        Second,
        Third
    }
```

в namespace2:

```
    public enum OnThePedestal
    {
        First,
        Second,
        Third
    }
```

И наконец, есть код "конвертера", который преобразует значения из одного неймспейса в другое: (сам "конвертер" содержится в таком месте, где есть ссылки на оба немспейса)

```
    public static OnThePedestal ToOnThePedestal (InTheRace src)
    {
            switch (src)
            {
                case InTheRace.First:
                    return OnThePedestal.First;

                case InTheRace.Second:
                    return OnThePedestal.Second;

                case InTheRace.Third:
                    return OnThePedestal.Third;
             }
    }
```

Что то мне подсказывает, что человечество давно уже изобрело для таких смешных преобразований что то типа автомэппера.

Можно мне подсказать, как это делать "по умному"?

Спасибо!

Comment: А по каким архитектурным подходам так нельзя? У нас в проекте есть application, domain и domain.shared. Так вот domain.shared добавлен в application слой и domain, в итоге используется там где нужно, потому что enum это общая сущность на весь проект. Ну это я так вижу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае значения совпадают, можно просто делать каст

```
public static OnThePedestal ToOnThePedestal(InTheRace src)
{
    return (OnThePedestal)src;
}
```

Работает это потому что значения энумов одинаковые, полная эквивалентная запись выглядела бы вот так:

```
public enum InTheRace : int
{
    First = 0,
    Second = 1,
    Third = 2
}
```

```
public enum OnThePedestal : int
{
    First = 0,
    Second = 1,
    Third = 2
}
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо большое, что то я сам не подумал, прежде чем спросить... Даже так: public static OnThePedestal ToOnThePedestal(InTheRace src) => (OnThePedestal)src;  - потому, что краткость - сестра нашего брата!

Answer (score 0):

```
Enum.ToObject(typeof(OnThePedestal), src)
```